# How to render pixelated 3D?

Tags: rendering, pixel

I'd like to know how to render games like a.e. Imscared https://gamejolt.com/games/imscared-a-pixelated-nightmare/10058
Its a great game and I wanted some games with a similar art style so..... 
Yeah!
thanks! :D

Comment: What stops you from simply making the resolution smaller and scaling it?

Comment: Actually! I considered something like this, but I didn't think it would look like wanted it to but I'll try it and write how it worked out

Comment: Why wouldn't it work for your case? I imagine you could just use low res textures and then disable linear texture sampling and lower the resolution of your frame to get the effect in Imscared.

Comment: Everything else would have to be dealt on within the shader layer on the gpu directly.

Comment: [This game](https://nothke.itch.io/normans-sky) is just an upscaled low resolution Unity game

Comment: Related: [Has anyone ever made a shader that produces something similar to pixel art?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/147549/21890)

Answer (score 0):

You just render the game in a lower resolution and then upscale it without interpolation to achieve large pixels.

The one thing where you would need a shader for is reducing the number of colors. You can do that with a pixel shader which only outputs a reduced color palette. You can do that by simply discarding the last few bits of the R, G and B component.